# Deploying a non-Web app (python) on IBM Bluemix without procfile?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

manifest.yml file:

```
---
applications:
 - name: myapp1
   memory: 512M
   command: python abc.py
   no-route: true
```

Procfile:

```
web: python abc.py
```

When i delete the Procfile my script does not run, even though i have specified a command to start the script in manifest file. Also, the fact the Procfile has web: in it makes me think it's trying to run it as a webapp? it is not meant to run as a webapp with an open port, it is only meant to make outbound connections.

Answer (score 0):

The procfile may be needed, depending on the Cloud Foundry version (only an old version). See this [Python buildpack information](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/python/index.html).

You can use the `command` section in the manifest file to specify the [start command](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#start-commands) (as shown in your example).

If your app is not a web app and does not have a route, [you need to specify the `no-route` option in the manifest file](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#no-route). Else the health checker will fail because it tries to access your app as "web app" and test its accessibility.

Comment: In addition to `no-route`, you need to add `health-check-type: process`.  Setting `no-route` used to be sufficient but configuring the health check was decoupled into it's own setting a while ago.  You can now set the health check to `process` directly and `no-route` is more of a formality, since there is no traffic to route to the app it makes sense not to map a route.

Comment: Simply using `cf push -c` or `command:` in your manifest should be sufficient to run a Python app (with the one documented exception, CF v245 and that version is quite old now).  You'll get a warning from the buildpack that you don't have a Procfile, but you can ignore that.  I have run a lot of Python apps this way.